# What can I do with this steering wheel?

Tags: piece-information, set-identification

I found this steering wheel + "dashboard" combination among some parts I bought.
[image: a grey steering wheel on an orange 4×4 mount]

What is it, in what kind of models is it used, and can I do anything else with the "dashboard" (for lack of a better word)? It seems like a rather large and specific part, just to hold a steering wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [steering wheel](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/30640) is from [4613-1: Turbo Chopper](http://brickset.com/sets/4613-1/Turbo-Chopper), as this is the only one with an orange version of this element.

Comment: Is that the only purpose of this part?

Comment: As far as LEGO is concerned? I think it's safe to say "yes". Unofficially? Well, imagination is a dangerous thing.

Comment: @SQB I guess you could use it anywhere you need a steering wheel and have a 4x4 space to fill instead of the usual 2x2 space.

Comment: The other _Turbo Chopper_ were in there, too. What an ugly model!